# React-native Android CodePush not working in Release mode

Tags: android, react-native, redux-saga, code-push, react-native-code-push

I have a `react-native` app with 3 `android` product flavours namely dev, prod and staging. The problem is that when I try to distribute the app via `Crashlytics`, basically when I build a release signed `apk` file, `CodePush` stops working. I am using `redux-saga` in my app and I am using the [`react-native-redux-saga`](https://github.com/geof90/react-native-code-push-saga) package to check for `CodePush` updates. All works fine on `iOS`, but not for `Android` as I mentioned above.

In my `Android` project, I have a `strings.xml` file for each of the product flavours that look like this:

```
<resources>
    <string moduleConfig="true" name="reactNativeCodePush_androidDeploymentKey">_My_CodePush_Key</string>
    <string name="app_name">MyApp Staging</string> 
</resources>
```

Product flavours setup looks like this:

```
productFlavors {

        prod {
            versionCode 6
            versionName "1.1"
        }

        staging {
            minSdkVersion 16
            applicationId 'com.myapp.staging'
            versionCode 6
            versionName "1.1"
        }

        dev {
            minSdkVersion 16
            applicationId 'com.myapp.dev'
            versionCode 6
            versionName "1.1"
        }
    }
```

And my `MainApplication.java` file looks like this:

```
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final MyReactNativeInstanceHolder mReactNativeHost = new MyReactNativeInstanceHolder(this) {

    @Override
    protected String getJSBundleFile() {
      return CodePush.getJSBundleFile();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            // ...Some packages
            new CodePush(getResources().getString(R.string.reactNativeCodePush_androidDeploymentKey), getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.DEBUG),
            // ...More packages
      );
    }
  };

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    CodePush.setReactInstanceHolder(getReactNativeHost());
    super.onCreate();
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
  }

  @Override
  public MyReactNativeInstanceHolder getReactNativeHost() {
      return mReactNativeHost;
  }
}
```

I tried to remove the `BuildConfig.DEBUG` parameter from the `CodePush` package, but the problem doesn't go away.

The `MyReactNativeInstanceHolder.java` file looks like this:

```
public class MyReactNativeInstanceHolder extends ReactNativeHost implements ReactInstanceHolder {
    protected MyReactNativeInstanceHolder(Application application) {
        super(application);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have also checked the keys for the `CodePush` app and there isn't any issue there. This issue is really strange and I would really like some help. Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: Does it work in debug build ?

Comment: @TGMCians Yes it does.

Comment: May be some issue with proguard ?

Comment: Hmm. Hadn't thought of that. Will do some investigation and get back to you. Any other theories?